# CSS/HTML - getting away from using the same select id on the page

Tags: html, css

I have 4 css files on my site, none of which I've written myself. I've commented them out (<-- --> with a !) to see which one is responsible for my select and it's because of this css:
http://pastebin.com/35ca1NEc

this is the code for the select:

```
<select id="demo-select2-1" class="form-control" name="question">
    <option value=''>None</option>
</select>
```

As you can see i use "demo-select2-1" and i know div/select ids cant be the same. I can change the number up to 5, but obviously i want to be able to use as many as i possibly could. I'm not very good with css and couldn't find in the code on how to change this.

If i don't use "demo-select2-X" then it wont look like i need it to.

Thanks if anyone of you could help me fix this

Comment: use class name to style you select and assign that class to all selects, instead os using id for styling use class

Comment: your pastebin is huge, why not simply copy and paste the CSS that relates to the select, `#demo-select2-1 { ... }` into your question. Makes your question more readable and all round *better*.

Comment: @Martin because i cant find it, which is why im asking for help

Comment: Your pastebin code doesn't have that specific `id` as an identifier that I can see, but it's 11k lines long and over 250Kb in size, this is ***HUGE*** for a CSS file, I would highly recommend dumping this and simply using another CSS layout system such as Bootstrap or one of the many other valid alternatives.

Comment: Also your `id` could *possibly* be influenced by Javascript swapping id names etc. at runtime in the browser...

Answer (score 0):

The `id` attribute has nothing to do with the `class` or your `css`.
You can just delete it.
Your css does not have "demo-select2-1" in it anyway. You are setting the style of the `<select>` control using the `class` attribute.

Comment: but if i remove id="demo-select2-1" then it reverts to another select.

Answer (score 0):

Let your `id` be as it is and apply css using class as a selector like`.class-name`, in this way you can apply same css to all select elements.